# Different output for array.clone() for 1- and multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Case 1, one-dimensional:

```
double[]vals = new double[4];
vals[0] = 1;
vals[1] = 123;
vals[2] = -1;
vals[3] = 2;

double[] vals4 = vals.clone();

double newval = 55;
vals[0] += newval;

for (int k=0;k<vals.length;k++){
  System.out.println("k= " + vals[k]);
  System.out.println("k= " + vals4[k]);               
}
```

The output is

```
k= 56.0
k= 1.0
k= 123.0
k= 123.0
k= -1.0
k= -1.0
k= 2.0
k= 2.0
```

Case 2, 2-dimensional:

```
double[][] vals3 = new double[][]{
                     {1,2},
                     {3,4}
                   };

double[][] vals2 = vals3.clone();
vals3[0][0] += 112;

for (int i=0;i<vals3.length;i++){
  for (int j=0;j<vals3[0].length;j++){
    System.out.println(vals2[i][j]);
    System.out.println(vals3[i][j]);
  }          
}
```

The output is

```
113.0
113.0
2.0
2.0
3.0
3.0
4.0
4.0
```

I use the same function, `array.clone()`, but why do the array elements change in the 2-dim case, when I change the array's inputs, but don't in the 1-dim case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java only has single dimensional arrays. A `double[][]` is an array of references to `double[]` so when you clone an array of references, you get another array of references to the same underlying arrays.

To do a deep clone, you can to create a new double[][] of the same size and clone the individual double[]s

e.g.

```
 public static double[][] deepClone(double[][] d) {
     double[][] ret = new double[d.length][];
     for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
         ret[i] = d[i].clone();
     return ret;
 }
```

Comment: would a System.arraycopy() be a better option for 2-dim case?

Comment: @Alex Using System.arraycopy doesn't alter the fact that you would be copying an array of references to arrays.

Comment: OK then, in the case when I change a value in a 2-dim array, how should I copy it to keep the values in the other one unchanged? With two for loops?

Comment: @Alex effectively yes, but the simplest solution is to use clone() in the manner in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Are they the same in terms of number of function evaluations/memory use/runtime?

Comment: @Alex If you were smart about it you could clone just the arrays you are altering and this would save some memory.  However, its usually simpler to clone everything.  If you are really concerned about performance the simplest thing is to avoid needing to clone in the first place, how you do that depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Well, I have an array, which I clone/fully copy, then apply certain changes to the newly copied array, and then copy some of these changes back to the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's because array.clone() copies references, in other words array clone just does "shallow" copy.